# How to select all and delete in Gmail App

Tags: gmail

I have a Nexus 5, there are a lots of sale emails come to my Gmail account. Right now I can only search in Gmail app, but I wonder how to delete all of results like in desktop version with select all and delete?

Comment: I think you need to manually select all the mails, there is no 'select all' option that I know of.

Comment: @NicolaBastianello Thanks, that is sad... ToT

Answer (score -1):

It is better to make rules and categorize email base on sender, Subject, and then select them for delete. Currently gmail app not provide select all and delete.